# Is there a way to run an Android Unity game in Windows?

Tags: unity, android, windows, cross-platform, mono

I was wondering, given a generic Unity game built for Android (with no desktop version), if I could somehow run it on windows (not in an android emulator) by using the windows version of mono.

The theory is that the script assembly (if the scripting was done in c#) is separate from the game engine.

I tried replacing the Data folder of a windows game with the Managed folder from the Android apk but got this error:

> Failed to load PlayerSettings (internal index #0). Most likely data
>   file is corrupted, or built with mismatching editor and platform
>   support versions.

Is there some tool I can use to change the platform of a third party unity game in order to play it ?

I'm not an unity developer myself but my concern is that games could use features not supported on desktop...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about issues met while developing a game as described in the [help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help), but about how to "hack" a third party game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is No.

When a game is compiled, it includes all assets for the platform it is compiled for only. This means the android version includes code of how to handle everything with Android's libraries. As a result, this is an android game, almost oblivious to the fact that it was made with Unity, as such, the only ways to run it are the same as if it was any other android app.

Comment: Alright, I got to use an emulator.